# Android USB to Samsung Eclipse Cannot Connect

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, connect

Right now I am trying to connect to Samsung Captivate. I see the device, but adb devices shows and empty list.  Debugging in Eclipse I cannot see the device.  I see it in the Windows 7 device list however.  phone says connected.  But adb devices does not list anything. What else do I need to do?

Comment: Go through this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html , this may help you.

Comment: well the docs says the android adb drivers are just for a few of the devices, the rest goto the oem for details.  This seems to be leading to kies but I am not clear if Samsung Kies is drivers or not, and what ADB driver might be used in conjunction?

Comment: Now I have seen sometime you can add to the google adb drivers inf file some specifiers, but you know no one ever says where those specifiers come from.  I am not a EE, and I have know idea what the entries in this file are for.

Comment: @Samsung kies is the PC suite

Comment: ok well article seems to point to OEM -> set of drivers including Android drivers. I will try installing them again but I don't see the ADB Interface got installed.  Found this article.  http://voxigee.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/using-adb-to-install-applications/

Comment: The article indicates that I should see three entries for the drivers

Comment: What I am seeing is the composite USB entry, a modem entry but on ADB Interface.  So when I type adb devices as indicated in the article nothing shows

Comment: Have you enabled developers options on your phone?

Answer (score 1):

Samsung has a separate driver for connecting their Android devices for to Windows machines. I think there is an option in Kies to install this.

Comment: ok well I installed the Samsung Captivate drivers, and I see the Samsung device in explorer.  But how for adb to detect.  I run adb devices and see nothing

Comment: I am seeing the device now in device manager it says SGH-I897 says device is working properly.  But how do I get adb to detect this? It just does not show up in eclipse when debugging. How do I make adb or eclipse see this device?  Thanks

Comment: try 'adb kill-server' and then 'adb start-server'

Comment: still does not list any devices

Comment: I clearly see the device under portal devices.  It says its working properly.  Is there some way to point to this device?

Comment: where on earth is adb checking for this device?

Comment: what is the option in Kies refer to?

Comment: guys could someone explain this to me.  I see there are captivate drivers but are these the right one for adb?  I see there is also the google usb drivers. When I try to switch to this I get message that windows (7) thinks the best driver is already installed.

Comment: I have two Samsung phones, all I needed to do is to install KIES version for these phones and plug in the phones by USB in Kies mode with debugging mode on and the adb drivers were working. Sometimes I have to plug and unplug the phone few times to connect properly.

Comment: ok I am downloading Kies software for captivate which appears to be the same as for Galaxy.  What do you mean by Plug in the phones by USB in Kies mode?  what puts it in keys mode?

Comment: When you say the ADB drivers were working that means what?  That you could then install some ADB driver?  which ADB driver?

Comment: Is Samsung Kies drivers or just a tool.  And what ADB driver would I need for ADB to find the device when I type adb devices or run the debugger in eclipse?

Comment: After installing Kies I did not need to do any orther set up but to plug in the mobile. When a Samsung mobile is pluged, it ask's me which usb connection mode I want. Also in settings>application>development I have enabled USB debugging. That is all I had to do.

Comment: Kies seems to work. However I thought I had USB debugging enabled because I saw the grayed out but checked! option.  I did not have it enabled.  Thanks guys for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is to connect via wifi, so there is no installation of drivers needed.

First
you need to download the [shell terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.acr.shellterminalemulator) on your android phone.
make sure both your android phone and computer are on the same wifi connection.
after downloading the application, open it and type this:

1. type "su" and press Enter.
2. type "setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555" and press Enter.
3. type "stop adbd" and press Enter.
4. type "start adbd" and press Enter.

after that.

navigate through your SDK folder wherein you can find an "Adb.exe" and open that in CMD and type this.

1. type "adb connect " and press Enter.

and you are done.