# Android Debug Bridge and Samsung Captivate

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, adb

I have tried installing the Samsung Captivate Drivers, but ADB does not see them.  I have got the google adb drivers in sdk directory but everytime i try to install this driver it says that Windows think I have the best driver for the device.  It keeps the MTB driver.  I have tried uninstalling but MTB driver keeps coming back.  I am trying to get the debug bridge to work to a Samsung Captivate.  adb devices shows nothing.

Comment: which device model do u have?

Comment: I have a new AT&T Samsung Captivate

Comment: under portable devices I am seeing SGH-I897

Comment: Driver files wpdMTPDr.dll in system 32

Comment: Do I need to switch to the google adb driver for to enable ADB for this device?

Comment: So far I have had trouble switching the driver from MTB to google android adb driver.  It insists that I have the right driver when I uninstall and try to install adb driver

Comment: Do I need to add something to the android_winusb.inf file?

Comment: yes its enabled.  it looks greyed out but its enabled.

Comment: totally confused about kies and ADB, I don't see the relationship to ADB at all.  I am trying to run debugging bridget in eclipse, and I just want adb to find the device when i run adb devices

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919506/android-usb-to-samsung-eclipse-cannot-connect and in any case is not a programming specific question and is probably better asked at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

try to use Samsung Kies. It has samsung drivers with in.

you can find it here :
http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/main/supportMain.do

works fine for me with the Samsung i5700 on Win7 x64

Comment: Well I havce installed kies.  Not really sure that this could possibly have to do with ADB debugging?  What settings do you use when you have ADB and Kies working together my friend.

Comment: please be more specific.  works fine for me means what?  that you are running adb and kies together.  If so, how do you connect.  Should I see in the devices area an Android ADB Bridge and not just modem etc settings.

Comment: I assume you mean you use Kies setting for USB connetion right?

Comment: How do you use Kies and ADB together?  Please answer this specifically how do you run them together.  I have installed Kies requested it install drivers, which it did and than I still see nothing when i run adb devices

Comment: None of the USB drivers works on my Win7 with my samsung device. im using eclipse for development and i needed to debug my application on a real device. so i found out that this kies application has win7 drivers. i did nothing special. i have just installed the kies and began to see my device on running android device list. hope this would help

Comment: also i can see my device in the "adb devices" list

Answer (score 0):

Installing [Samsung New PC Studio](http://www.samsung.com/us/PCstudio) worked for my Samsung Fascinate.  You get a bit more than just drivers, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of installing the Samsung Captivate Drivers.  (Some people have to reinstall them several times) and then just making sure that USB is definitely set for debugging.  This should work.  The Android application itself needs also to be enabled for debugging  android:debuggable="true" in the Android-Manifest.  This is what it needs.  Note this is how to get ADB working so that if you type adb devices you will see the Samsung device. Kies is an option for file sharing.